# Usar o resultado de uma array como value de um insert - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array, sql-insert, value

Boa Noite, estou com um duvida.

Estou fazendo upload de um arquivo e extraindo seu conteúdo e inserindo no meu banco de dados, mais estou com uma duvida como usar o **array** como o **value**

Meu arquivo consta com uma sequencia de números separados por 15 bloco dividido por um **|** e uma quebra de linhas entre a cada 15 blocos

Ex. do Arquivo de leitura
**02|01|020320171212|524419188|206|000011900173|03|700000|700000|644490|033438|2622221|C|M|C| |02|01|020320171427|524418372|206|000011915070|01|31900|31900|31102|250802|2623485|C|M|D|**

Ex. do meu codigo *upload.php*

```
<?php
include 'conect.php';
///RECEBE PELO METODO POST
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
///ABRE O ARQUIVO
$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
///SEPARA OS BLOCOS
$array=explode("|",$content);

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dados (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p) VALUES ( '".$array[$i]."' ");
/// Está dando o erro de Query was empty

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

}


if(mysql_affected_rows() != 0){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.alert('$fileName Enviado!');</script>";
echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=lista.php">';
exit;
}

}
?>
```

Quero inserir no banco de dados as informações que constam nesse arquivo por isso criei uma tabela com as colunas em nomes de a,b,c...

Se algum puder me ajudar, fico muito grato!

Att;
Danilo Braga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **/!\ Essa publicação NÃO LEVA em consideração NENHUM aspecto de segurança**!

Isso `VALUES ( '".$array[$i]."' ")` não existe, ao menos não nesse contexto, além do erro que existe em sua *query* que não tem o `)` ao final.

---

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$valoresParaQuery = trim( trim( str_replace('|', "','", $linha) ) , "','");

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dados (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p) VALUES ( '" . $string . "') ");
```

O `str_replace` vai substituir todos os `|` por `,` e o `trim` irá remover qualquer `','` que esteja antes ou depois, dessa forma:

```
INSERT INTO dados (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p) VALUES ('02','01','020320171212','524419188','206','000011900173','03','700000','700000','644490','033438','2622221','C','M','C')
```

*Isso ainda tem erro devido a haver apenas 15 valores contra 16 colunas, para corrigir isso REMOVA a coluna que é o AUTO_INCREMENT*, assim removendo o `a`.

---

Porém você diz que tem "uma quebra de linhas entre a cada 15 blocos", se deseja inserir todas as linhas faça um *loop* por linha, *isso não está sendo feito no código atual*.

Utilize por exemplo:

```
include 'conect.php';

if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0){

    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

    $arquivo = file($tmpName);
    // Veja se o arquivo está exatamente no local, o `tmp_name` não informa o caminho do arquivo, normalmente na pasta /tmp/!

    foreach($arquivo as $linha){

        $valoresParaQuery = trim( trim( str_replace('|', "','", $linha) ) , "','");

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dados (b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p) VALUES ('" . $valoresParaQuery . "') ");

    }

}
```

Dessa forma a cada linha será feito o processo descrito lá em cima, trocando o `|` por `,` e então executando a query.

*Nem irei comentar sobre problemas de segurança e vulnerabilidades porque são muitas*

Comment: Bom dia @Inkeliz obrigado pela ajuda, mais o erro ainda persiste. Foi corrigido a questão do `)` no final da `mysql_querry` e o fato de existir 16 colunas para 15 elementos é que não tinha customizado os nomes das colunas, onde `a` seria a coluna com nome `ID` e ela será **AUTO_INCREMENT**  vou utilizar o _NULL_ como primeiro elemento do `VALUE` . A principio não quero salvar  o arquivo em nenhum diretório, e sim fazer uma leitura temporária, por isso não indiquei o caminho do arquivo.  estou utilizando esse ultimo código enviado, mais o erro de `Query was empty` ainda persiste.

Comment: Eu corrigi um erro, mas possívelmente o seu problema é totalmente outro. Verifique se um `var_dump(file($tmpName))` retorna o arquivo. Eu testei exatamente o código acima usando MySQLi usando PHP 7.1, estou deixando disponível em https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5cc2lz1uwwzag5/187952.zip?dl=0. Se é "AUTO_INCREMENT" não precisa mencionar ele.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content= str_replace("|".Chr(10)."|", Chr(10), $content);
$content= str_replace(Chr(10)."|", Chr(10), $content);

    $array= explode(Chr(10),$content);

    $result = count($array);                

    for ($k = 0; $k < $result; $k++) {
        $bloco = $array[$k];
        $aDest = explode("|", $bloco);
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO spedido (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o) VALUES ('".$aDest[0]."','".$aDest[1]."','".$aDest[2]."','".$aDest[3]."','".$aDest[4]."','".$aDest[5]."','".$aDest[6]."','".$aDest[7]."','".$aDest[8]."','".$aDest[9]."','".$aDest[10]."','".$aDest[11]."','".$aDest[12]."','".$aDest[13]."','".$aDest[14]."') ");
```

Funcionou redondinho no meu banco com

$content="01|01|020320171212|524419188|206|000011900173|03|700000|700000|644490|033438|2622221|C|M|C|
|02|01|020320171427|524418372|206|000011915070|01|31900|31900|31102|250802|2623485|C|M|D
|03|01|020320171427|524418444|206|000011915070|01|31900|31900|31102|250802|2623485|C|M|D";